# htmx form + gin unable to properly read request body

Tags: go, go-gin, htmx

I have this form using htmx, trying to send the input value of the first input to the Gin server

```html
<form hx-post="/addToDo" hx-ext="json-enc" hx-trigger="submit" hx-target="#todos" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <input type="text" placeholder="todo" name="todo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<ol id="todos"></ol>
```

The Gin server

```golang
r.POST("/addToDo", func(c *gin.Context) {
    fmt.Println(c.Request.Body)
    // ^this prints "&{0xc0000b2000 <nil> <nil> false true {0 0} false false false 0xeaee20}"

    jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("something went wrong here boys")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(jsonData)
    // ^this prints "[116 111 100 111 61 104 101 108 108 111]"
})
```

I thought about having the post request url include the input value as a parameter but I'm fairly certain there's a way to do that in the request body and I'm just missing something. How do I get the request body or query the "todo" input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just getting a string as a []byte.

```
  a := []byte{116, 111, 100, 111, 61, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111}
  fmt.Print(string(a))
```

`todo=hello`

I don't think you need to parse this todo=hello yourself. You can just use:

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormValue

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @andrew-arrow, your server gets `x-www-form-urlencoded` data instead of JSON encoded data. That means `hx-ext="json-enc"` does not work as expected. It's most likely because you forgot to include the `json-enc` extension.  Check your page to make sure it contains something like this (see [The `json-enc` Extension](https://htmx.org/extensions/json-enc/)):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/json-enc.js"></script>
```

And gin has provided utils to bind JSON data ([ShouldBindJSON](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindJSON)). See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var page = `<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.2"
      integrity="sha384-L6OqL9pRWyyFU3+/bjdSri+iIphTN/bvYyM37tICVyOJkWZLpP2vGn6VUEXgzg6h"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/json-enc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form
      hx-post="/addToDo"
      hx-ext="json-enc"
      hx-trigger="submit"
      hx-target="#todos"
      hx-swap="outerHTML"
    >
      <input type="text" placeholder="todo" name="todo" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <ol id="todos"></ol>
  </body>
</html>
`

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        _, err := c.Writer.WriteString(page)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    })
    r.POST("/addToDo", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var todo struct {
            Todo string `json:"todo"`
        }
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&todo); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        // Do not do this in production code because it's not safe against code injection.
        // Use the html/template package to generate the HTML fragment instead.
        if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(c.Writer, `<ol id="todos"><li>%s</li></ol>`, todo.Todo); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    })
    _ = r.Run()
}
```

Please note that the binding feature of gin can detect the `Content-Type` header and choose a binding engine accordingly. So you can write the code like this which supports both JSON encoded and `x-www-form-urlencoded` data:

```golang
var todo struct {
    Todo string `json:"todo" form:"todo"`
}
if err := c.ShouldBind(&todo); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```